# Daemon startup on Debian(existence of /sbin/service)

Tags: linux, debian, daemon, start-stop-daemon

What is the best way to start a service on Debian through a program? I used to use '/sbin/service  start', but I recently came across a system where '/sbin/service' did not exist, so starting the daemon would fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy and customize `/etc/init.d/skeleton` (e.g. into `/etc/init.d/specksyn`) and add symlinks from e.g. `/etc/rc2.d/S99specksyn` to it, etc. etc.